# Combining code of multiple indicators (is it possible?)

Tags: pine-script

Is it possible to combine these indicators into a single code?

SuperTrend (10, 2)
VWAP
VWMA (20)
Volume

Answer (score 0):

Their source codes are available and `volume` is a built-in variable. So, yes, it is possible. However, you cannot display volume bars as it is in the original script.